# Возможно ли в поле grid view разметить другой grid view?

Tags: php, html, yii, table

Вот так это должно выглядеть :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если такое возможно то поделитесь кусочком кода или  ссылкой

Answer (score 1):

Например так можно:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ... ,
    'columns' => [
        ...     
        [
            'attribute' => 'your_attribute',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                $otherDataProvider = ...;
                return GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $otherDataProvider,
                    ...
                ]);
            },
        ],
        ...
     ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: спасибо, будет время проверю, но я по коду уже вижу должно заработать